# How I can restore original repositories list?

Tags: updates, repositories

Once I tried to install Opera browser to Elementary OS. OK it was work for one time as minim. But after this action my repositories list was broken and elementary cannot update itself because some mistakes in access to repositories. Please tell me how I can restore original repositories list?

Answer (score 1):

The main repository file is `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the sources you add usually go there as lines or into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder as `*.list` files. I do not know your linux and terminal skills but you can edit the above file using terminal.

**If you attempt to do this, do a backup of the file first**, for example into your home folder with `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/`  .

In order to edit the file you have to type into terminal `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and you will open this file for edit after you authorize yourself as an administrator user. If the only problem is the opera repo and it is inside this file you can comment it with the `#` sign in the beginning of the lines, save it with <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and close it with <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

If the broken repos are not in this file they should be into the `sources.list.d` folder and you can move them to a backup folder with `sudo mkdir ~/backup` to create the folder and the move command is `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/file-you-want-to-remove.list ~/backup/`. You can see the folder contents with `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` , the files with the `.save` extention are backups of the corresponding `.list` files.

In this folder should remain the **`elementary.list`** file which contains information for the main elementary os repo on launchpad, **you have to keep it there**.

All other files can be safely moved, if you need them back - just reverse the source and detination of the move command - `sudo mv ~/backup/file-to-restore.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`  .