# update problem due to the repository

Tags: updates

thank you for the chance to post my problem.
I am trying to update and receive the following

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: There is no bionic (elementary os hera is based on it) version on this repository - http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu/dists/ . You have to disable/remove it from the sources list Follow this guide for fix - https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/24105/12483

Comment: Thank you for your time and response. Can you help me remove or disable it from the sources list?

Comment: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/24105/12483